# Pass to javascript function div class arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on some website. I have a question. How to give class name to JS function.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="grid-item">
    <div id="info">
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="hidden: hidden;">
        </div>
        <img onmouseover="show(this)" onmouseout="hide(this)" src="'smiley.gif'" />
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS function look like this

```
function show(x) {
    x.style.hidden= visible;
}

function hide(x) {
    x.style.hidden= hidden;
}
```

But in **onmouseover** and **onmouseout** i do not want to use **this**. I what to show or hide

```
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="hidden: hidden;"></div>
```

from html. How to do this?
My idea is to give to this div id and then that id to pass to function, but how to do this.

Remeber that i will have a lot of div tags (), for every picture.

And also how to position that div on right top corner of image?

Thanks.

Comment: i do not understand the question... you want to hide the images with JS? or with HTML?  by the way, x.style.hidden=visible and x.style.hidden=hidden  work? si do not think you use the correct syntax

Comment: *And also how to position that div on right top corner of image?* Are you aware that none of the images in your html will render because you need to use absolute (exact) urls to any image you post here, right? Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, then use this.

```
function show(x) {
    $(x).prev('div.glyphicon.glyphicon-search').show();
}
function hide(x) {
    $(x).prev('div.glyphicon.glyphicon-search').hide();
}
```

But it is preferred to do something like this. Add a class to these images 
`smiley`.

```
<img class="smiley" src="'smiley.gif'" />
```

Then

```
$('img.smiley').on('hover', show, hide);

function show() {
    $(this).prev('div.glyphicon.glyphicon-search').show();
}
function hide() {
    $(this).prev('div.glyphicon.glyphicon-search').hide();
}
```

or using the `mouseover` / `mouseout` events and event delegation,

```
$(document)
    .on('mouseover', 'img.smiley', show)
    .on('mouseover', 'img.smiley', hide);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look on the demo, it has all the details. Good luck.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');


function show(x) {
  x.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function hide(x) {
  x.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

```css
* {
  background: transparent;
}
.grid-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.info {
  position: relative;
}
.btn,
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.btn {
  right: 20%;
  top: 15%;
}
.logo {
  right: 5%;
  top: 10%;
}
article { margin-top: 5%; }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<div class="grid-item">
  <div id="info" onmouseover="show(btn)" onmouseout="hide(btn)">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
      <input type="search" /><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
    </button>

    <img class="logo" src="http://static.tumblr.com/7882552ad1b500434662c7b0ae2f3d74/pvsmty4/cp3n1htcy/tumblr_static_and_heres_the_transparent_one__48af21dc5f513bb7b872ca0128f7fcf9.png" width="100" />
  </div>
</div>
<h1>Fixed:</h1>
<article>
<ul>
  <li>CSS Property <code>visibility: hidden | visible | collapse (Tables Only)</code></li>
  <li>There is no such thing as the <del>hidden</del> property only hidden as a value.</li>
  <li>If your question concerns images, then you must include them in your code as an absolute url <samp>(ex. http://imgur.com/path/to/img.png)</samp></li>
  <li>Smiley face image is on the right side as requested.</li>
  <ul>
  <li>Set <code>position: relative;</code> to the parent element of target element.
  <li>Set the target element to <code>position: absolute;</code></li>
    <li>Position target element with <code>top, bottom, left, right</code>
      </ul>
      <li>See <a href="https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/visibility/">Visibility</a>
      <li>See <a href="https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/">Position</a>
    
  </ul>
</article>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```